# Anchor tag in iframe via fancybox

Tags: javascript, iframe, tags, fancybox, anchor

I am using fancybox to open an iframe and scroll to an anchor tag but apart from IE where it works perfectly, all other browsers are not consistent and stop in a different place that not the anchor.

I think the problem could be with JavaScript according to what I read here http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/927172 but I can't figure out how to fix my code.

here is the link:
`<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="cost_of_hire.php#cupcakeanchor"><img src="images/services/4.jpg" alt="" /></a>`

and the anchor:
    `<a name="cupcakeanchor">CUP CAKE MAKING PARTY<br />£0.00</a>`

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

PS.: In IE, all is working, in Chrome and Firefox, from 12 links I have, 8 work perfectly, in Safari 6 work and in Opera none of them work.

Comment: have you tried `<a id="cupcakeanchor">`?

Answer (score 0):

In Fancybox, anchors do not work on the ,  and others. Try with a .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open an iframe with anchor you can't use directly but it's possible to accomplish with javascript. At least it works for me (used in Prestashop).

My link:

```
<a href="http://mylink.com/blabla/#myanchor" class="iframe-pv">Mi linkable text</a>
```

My code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.iframe-pv', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchor = '';
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var anchorIdx = url.indexOf('#');

    if (anchorIdx > -1) {
        anchor = url.substring(anchorIdx, url.length);
        url = url.substring(0, anchorIdx);
    }

    if(url.indexOf('content_only=') == -1) {
        url += (url.indexOf('?') > -1) ? '&' : '?';
        url += 'content_only=1';
    }

    if (!!$.prototype.fancybox){
        $.fancybox({
            'padding':  20,
            'width':    '70%',
            'height':   '70%',
            'type':     'iframe',
            'href':     url + anchor
        });
    }
});
```

I hope it helps :)